# Problems getting specific data out of response from ajax call

Tags: json, ajax

The json file I am calling can be found [here](http://datatank.stad.gent/4/bevolking/totaalaantalinwoners.json). It contains population data for regions in Ghent (a city in Belgium) during a specific year. I use the following code to retrieve the data, the array where i store the response data is called "inwonersperwijk":

```
function(key,value) {
$.each(key,function(key,value){
       inwonersperwijk.push(value);
    });
    $.each(key[0], function (key, value) {
      years.push(key);
    });
}
,
error: function(er){
    console.log(er);
}});
```

which returns an object that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itlf1.jpg).

What I am trying to do is retrieve the "wijk" in each of these objects. When I try to use inwonersperwijk[0].year_1999 for example, it returns the corresponding data just fine.

But when I want to retrieve the "wijk" part of the data by using inwonersperwijk[0].wijk, I get an undefined. Could anyone possibly help me out with this?

Comment: first you caount the length of that array and assign it to any variable and than iterate your array using this length pass counter in this array as you passed already, because if you directly iterate the array it will every character so better store length in variable and then get it, hopt it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your JSON source file I can see that the indexes for the years are `"year_1999"`, `"year_2000"` and so on, but the index for the *wijk* is actually "`\ufeffwijk"`. The `\ufeff` is a non-breaking space (see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm)).

If you look at your output array screenshot, you will see that the year indices have no quotes, while the index for wijk does (it's `"wijk"` not `wijk`). This is why you get undefined: the index for `wijk` does not actually exist.

You're better off first filtering the `\ufeff` characters out of the JSON before parsing it.

Comment: I ended up cheating and just downloading the file and replacing \ufeffwijk by wijk.